# ¿Cómo puedo parar el método accept de serverSocket?

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente código:

```
                try{
                ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(puerto);
                int contador=0;
                int contadorAnterior=0;
                while(!end){

                        Socket s=ss.accept();
                        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                        stringData=input.readLine();
                        output.println("FROM SERVER" + stringData.toUpperCase());
                        output.flush();
                        if(stringData!=null){
                            contador++;
                            //input.reset();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recibido"+ stringData,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no se ha recibido un mensaje nuevo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            end=true;
                        }

                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String conta=String.valueOf(contador);
                        updateUI(conta);
                        if(stringData.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")){
                            end=true;
                            output.close();
                            s.close();
                            break;
                        }
                        output.close();
                        s.close();




                }
                ss.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

y cuando llega a la línea Socket s=ss.accept();, se queda esperando a que entre una conexión, me gustaría hacer que tras unos segundos esperando, se corte la espera. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar [setSoTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-), puedes gestionar la interrupción java.io.InterruptedIOException o java.net.SocketTimeoutException para reaccionar al timeout.

por ejemplo:

```
   try{
     ss.setSoTimeout(3000);
     Socket s=ss.accept();
     //.... 
   }catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e){
     // gestiona aqui el timeout
   }
```

Comment: Perfecto, mil gracias!

Comment: solo como puntualización, puedes gestionar la interrupción java.io.InterruptedIOException o java.net.SocketTimeoutException para reaccionar al timeout. Marca la respuesta como válida si te sirvió para que los demas usuarios puedan reutilizarla.

Comment: @FranciscoTena Deberías poner eso (que el timeout se gestiona con una Exception) como parte de la respuesta

Comment: Creí que sería suficiente con el enlace a la documentación oficial, donde lo pone explicitamente. Añadido a la respuesta de todas maneras.